# Iterating over variables java

Tags: java

I am increasing in a random fashion each variable until the sum of points to assign is equal to 0. Is there any smart way, where I can reduce the amount of code in method generate(), for example by iterating through variables instead of listing them one by one?

```
public class RandomStatsGenerator {

    int Strength = 3;
    int Dexterity = 3;
    int Constitution = 3;
    int Intelligence = 3;
    int Wisdom = 3;
    int Charisma = 3;
    int sum = 45;
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 18;

    public void generate() {
        while (sum> 0 && Strength <= MAX_VALUE) {
            boolean test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true) {
                Strength++;
                sum--;
            }
            test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && Dexterity <= MAX_VALUE) {
                Dexterity++;
                sum--;
            }
            test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && Constitution <= MAX_VALUE) {
                Constitution++;
                sum--;
            }
            test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && Intelligence <= MAX_VALUE) {
                Intelligence++;
                sum--;
            }
            test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && Wisdom <= MAX_VALUE) {
                Wisdom++;
                sum--;
            }
            test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && Charisma <= MAX_VALUE) {
                Charisma++;
                sum--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Strength: " + Strength + ".");
        System.out.println("Dexterity: " + Dexterity + ".");
        System.out.println("Constitution: " + Constitution + ".");
        System.out.println("Intelligence: " + Intelligence + ".");
        System.out.println("Wisdom: " + Wisdom + ".");
        System.out.println("Charisma: " + Charisma + ".");
    }

    private boolean getRandomBoolean() {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply generate a random number 0-5 and increment the corresponding variable (0 -> Strength, 1-> Dexterity). Repeat that until your sum is equal to the max value you want to have.

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions and use lower letter for naming variables

Comment: Unrelated, but everyone that’s saying to use an array are incorrect: don’t do that. These are character class attributes, with names, separated logic, and rules. Please don’t use an array.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, doing it like that will favor the attributes at the top of the check sequence, you should rather pick one by (a single) random number and increment it.

Answer (score 2):

code duplication like yours can be reduced by extractig *similar code* to *parameterized methods*.

to be able to do that we need to convert yout code a little to convert the *similar code* to *identical code*:

```
public void generate() {
    while (sum> 0 && Strength <= MAX_VALUE) {
        int property = Strength;
        boolean test = getRandomBoolean();            
        if (test == true && property <= MAX_VALUE) { // added second condition to catch up with the following ifs
            property++;
            sum--;
        }
        Strength = property;

        property = Dexterity;
        test = getRandomBoolean();
        if (test == true && property <= MAX_VALUE) {
            property++;
            sum--;
        }
        Dexterity = property;
        // same for the rest
```

now you have 5 lines of code that are exactly repeated:

```
        test = getRandomBoolean();
        if (test == true && property <= MAX_VALUE) {
            property++;
            sum--;
        }
```

You can select the first occurence of this 5 lines and apply your IDEs *extract method* refactoring. Your IDE will replace all occurrences of the selected lines.

```
public void generate() {
    while (sum> 0 && Strength <= MAX_VALUE) {
        int property = Strength;
        property=extracted(property);
        Strength = property;

        property = Dexterity;
        property=extracted(property);
        Dexterity = property;
        // same for the rest
}
private int extracted(int property){
        test = getRandomBoolean();
        if (test == true && property <= MAX_VALUE) {
            property++;
            sum--;
        }
        return property;
}
```

of cause you should give the new method a better name during extaction. I just leave the name suggested by my IDE on purpose.

Finaly you can inline the variables in your original method:

```
  public void generate() {
        while (sum> 0 && Strength <= MAX_VALUE) {
            Strength = extracted(Strength);
            Dexterity = extracted(Dexterity);
            // same for the rest
    }
```

Comment: i would remove Strength <= MAX_VALUE as all points will be distributed when sum is empty and (18-3) * 6 > 45

Comment: @LaurentB I wnted to show a general approach for the OPs main problem. Of cause this code has much more things to improve...

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have just started learning Java, so all feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Enum for your attributes,

```
public enum Attribute {
  STRENGTH,
  DEXTERITY,
  CONSTITUTION,
  INTELLIGENCE,
  WISDOM,
  CHARISMA;
}
```

Then, create a map of the attributes to their values:

```
Map<Attribute, Integer> attributeValues = new HashMap<>();
attributeValues.put(Attribute.STRENGTH, 3);
attributeValues.put(Attribute.DEXTERITY, 3);
// ...
attributeValues.put(Attribute.CHARISMA, 3);
```

Pick a random attribute from the map and increase it:

```
Random rand = new Random();
Attribute toIncrement = Attribute.values()[rand.nextInt(Attributes.values().length)];
attributeValues.compute(toIncrement, (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

Put that in a loop, add code for tracking the sum and you should be done.

On a side note, I'd not go through all attributes for each iteration, checking each with a random boolean if you want to increase it as this will favor the the first attributes for increasing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map and iterate on the set of entries in your `while` loop:

```
private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
{
    map.put("Strength", 3);
    map.put("Dexterity", 3);
    map.put("Constitution", 3);
    map.put("Intelligence", 3);
    map.put("Wisdom", 3);
    map.put("Charisma", 3);
}

int sum = 45;

public void generate() {
    while (sum > 0 && map.get("Strength") <= MAX_VALUE) {

        map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            boolean test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test) {
                map.merge(entry.getKey(), 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
                sum--;
            }
        });
    }

    map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " 
       + entry.getValue() + "."));
}
```

If the default value for all variables is `3`, you can even simplify it further by using a list:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("Stength", "Dexterity", 
        "Constitution", "Intelligence", "Wisdom", "Charisma");
private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

int sum = 45;

public void generate() {
    do {
        map.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
            boolean test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test) {
                map.merge(entry.getKey(), 3, (a, b) -> a + b);
                sum--;
            }
        });
    } while (sum > 0 && map.get("Strength") <= MAX_VALUE);

    //...rest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple array and a for loop:

```
public class RandomStatsGenerator {

    int[] attributes = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    int sum = 45;
    static final int MAX_VALUE = 18;

    public void generate() {
        for (int i = 0; sum != 0; i++) {
            boolean test = getRandomBoolean();
            if (test == true && attributes[i] <= MAX_VALUE) {
                attributes[i]++;
                sum--;
            }
            if ( i == 5 ) {
                i = -1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Strength: " + attributes[0] + ".");
        System.out.println("Dexterity: " + attributes[1] + ".");
        System.out.println("Constitution: " + attributes[2] + ".");
        System.out.println("Intelligence: " + attributes[3] + ".");
        System.out.println("Wisdom: " + attributes[4] + ".");
        System.out.println("Charisma: " + attributes[5] + ".");
    }
}
```

Then afterwards, if you still want your attributes available as package private variables, you can define them after they've been set with the values from the array.

Comment: Yes, I'll admit it's not pretty, but it does work. i is incremented at the end of the loop, so it is set to 0 again for the next iteration. Alternatively, you can use two loops; one for i and one for sum.